# Invalid JSON text when updating JSON column on MySQL Community Server 8.0.22

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

**Current Version:**

- PHP Version 7.4.12
- MySQL Community Server - GPL 8.0.22

---

**Problem:**

When I was using **8.0.21** (MySQL Community Server - GPL), I update my JSON column like this without problem:

```
$desc = "Testing";
$sql = "
    UPDATE test SET
        test_json = JSON_SET(
            COALESCE(test_json, '{}'),
            '$.test', ?
        )
    WHERE test_pk = 123
";

$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_CONNECTION, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $desc);
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->error) echo $stmt->error;
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

After upgrade to **8.0.22**, I got this error:

```
Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function cast_as_json: "Invalid value." at position 0.
```

So now I had to do this to solve the problem:

```
'$.test', JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_QUOTE(?))
```

Without prepared statement no problem but of course that's not an option:

```
'$.test', 'Testing'
```

Why? What can I do to retain the original SQL string(no quote unquote)? I don't mind to add another codes before `$stmt->execute()`.

---

**Edited:**
I end up using PDO for this isu

Comment: Which PHP version are you using?

Comment: PHP Version 7.4.12